# How can i search first for a specific directory gif file and then continue to the rest?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, subdirectory

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     DirectoryInfo dir1 = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\Chocolade\AppData\Local\SatellitesImagesDownloads\SatellitesImagesDownloads\Countries\Israel\");
     fi = dir1.GetFiles("*.gif");

     foreach (FileInfo finfo in fi)
     {
         if (fi.Length > 0 && finfo.Length > 0)
         {
              timer1.Enabled = false;
              pictureBox1.Load(finfo.FullName);

              listView1.Items[0].Checked = true;
         }
     }
}
```

This is working fine for the directory Israel.

The timer interval is set to 100.

Once it found a gif file in directory Israel it's loading it to `pictureBox1` and checking the `CheckBox` in `listView1` for this item.

But now I want to change it and make that it will search all sub directories but first only for Israel. Once it found Israel and loaded the gif to the `pictureBox1` and checked the `CheckBox` then continue and search all other sub directories and when there are gif file in a sub directory check the checkbox for it in the `listView1`.

The items in the `listView1` are by name of the countries.

Now I changed the code but it's not yet doing what I want:

Instead searching only in directory Israel it's now searching all sub directories under Countries.

But not sure how to continue from here.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     DirectoryInfo dir1 = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\Chocolade\AppData\Local\SatellitesImagesDownloads\SatellitesImagesDownloads\Countries\");
     fi = dir1.GetFiles("*.gif", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

     foreach (FileInfo finfo in fi)
     {
         if (fi.Length > 0 && finfo.Length > 0)
         {
              timer1.Enabled = false;
              pictureBox1.Load(finfo.FullName);

              listView1.Items[0].Checked = true;
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need a timer at all? It seems to be a search in a background thread which need to update UI using `Invoke` when finding a result.

Comment: If you have not a huge number of files in your directory: search all gif file names from root directory and sub directories, sort the list of file names at your convenience and then start your timer to display the next item of the list and increment the index of next item initially set to 0).

Comment: If you have found more than one *.gif file your loop will load only the last. Is this intended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually described your algorithm in words already:

> but first only for Israel once it found Israel loaded the gif to the pictureBox1 and checked the checkbox

The for-loop is actually not necessary here, since you will load the last file if you have found more than one you could just use the `Last()` method

```
DirectoryInfo dir1 = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\Chocolade\AppData\Local\SatellitesImagesDownloads\SatellitesImagesDownloads\Countries\Israel\");
fi = dir1.GetFiles("*.gif");

// if you have found any gif files at all
if (fi.Any())
{
    timer1.Enabled = false;
    pictureBox1.Load(fi.Last().FullName);

    listView1.Items[0].Checked = true;
}
```

> then continue and search all other sub directories and when there are gif file in a sub directory check the checkbox for it in the listView1.

```
fi = dir1.GetFiles("*.gif", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

// if you have found any gif files at all
if (fi.Any())
{
    timer1.Enabled = false;

    listView1.Items[0].Checked = true;
}
```

put these two code parts in your `timer1_Tick` event.

You could also combine them into an if-else statement, since your checkbox will be checked already if you have found a gif-file in the Israel folder.

Comment: Maybe i can do it also without using a timer ? I will make a new question